# Python filtered and date sorted list

Tags: python, list

How would I have to create a date modified sorted list with Python of all files in /var/log starting with yum.log

```
ls -la /var/log/yum.log*                                                                                                      [17-01-04 11:36:41]
-rw-------. 1 root root     0 Jan  1 03:45 /var/log/yum.log
-rw-------. 1 root root 16062 Jan 13  2016 /var/log/yum.log-20160113
-rw-------. 1 root root 36020 Dec 22 16:28 /var/log/yum.log-20170101
```

This code creates the list, but it is sorted by name.

```
logdir = '/var/log'
yum_logs = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('yum.log')])
```

How can I sort this list by date modified so the newest yum logfile comes first?

Comment: You could always split the row into pieces or use regexp to draw out the data you want. Then pass it to [time.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime). But it would be neat if you would try yourself first and if you bump into any errors we'd be able to help :) The list is sorted by name because `listdir()` will print out the filenames only relative to the path you put in. If you want size or date data, use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Comment: `by date modified`.. Do you mean these dates: `20160113`, `20170101` or these: `Jan 13  2016`, `Dec 22 16:28`..?

Comment: @Andersson He's looking at getting `os.stat(path_to_file)` and sort the list based on that.

Comment: these: Jan 13 2016, Dec 22 16:28 and Jan 16:28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.getmtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime):

```
logdir = '/var/log'
yum_logs = [f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('yum.log')]
sorted(yum_logs, key=lambda f: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(logdir, f)))
```

You can pass `reverse=True` to `sorted` to reverse the order:

```
sorted(yum_logs, key=lambda f: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(logdir, f)), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You get modification time using [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat):

```
logdir = '/var/log'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('yum.log')]
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.stat(os.path.join(logdir, x)).st_mtime)
```

Comment: This lists the oldest yum logfile first, I would like to have to newest logfile first in the list.

Comment: files.sort(..., reverse=True)